# Decimal error in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to input a csv file that I can then use to do calculations:

```
import csv
data=[]
file=input ("Enter file name: ")
with open(file,"r") as f:
      reader=csv.reader(f)

            for row in reader:
                  data.append([x.strip(";") for x in row])
            print(data)

print("Calculate COV")
lst= data
spl= [x.split(";") for y in lst for x in y]
flattened = [float(x) for y in spl for x in y if x]   
print (flattened)
```

But I keep getting this when I use decimal numbers:

> [['13', '25;12', '97;13', '12;13', '47;13', '44;13', '09;12', '86;12', '78;12', '91;12', '93;12', '91;13', '11'], ['12', '92;13', '42;13', '58;13', '7;13', '62;13', '7;13', '31;12', '86;12', '59;12', '81;13', '46;12', '9'], ['13', '39;13', '5;13', '29;13', '26;13', '38;13', '45;13', '46;11', '95;12;12', '57;13', '22;12', '88'], ['12', '48;13', '76;13', '7;13', '77;13', '08;13', '48;13', '25;12', '31;12', '56;12', '56;12', '95;13', '38'], ['12', '52;14', '07;14', '46;14', '13;13', '98;14', '07;13', '92;12', '7;13', '01;12', '79;13;13', '13']]

When I should have this:

> [13.25, 12.97, 13.12, 13.47, 13.44, 13.09, 12.86, 12.78, 12.91, 12.93, 12.91, 13.11, 12.92, 13.42, 13.58, 13.7, 13.62, 13.7, 13.31, 12.86, 12.59, 12.81, 13.46, 12.9, 13.39, 13.5, 13.29, 13.26, 13.38, 13.45, 13.46, 11.95, 12.57, 13.22, 12.88, 12.48, 13.76, 13.7, 13.77, 13.08, 13.48, 13.25, 12.31, 12.56, 12.56, 12.95, 13.38, 12.52, 14.07, 14.46, 14.13, 13.98, 14.07, 13.92, 12.7, 13.01, 12.79, 13.0, 13.13]

Comment: Can you post the contents of `data` after the csv parsing is done? And does that have the correct contents?

Comment: Can we see a sample of the CSV data?

Comment: @sharth The content of data is the first list I posted, and no it is not correct but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Matt This is the CSV I'm using: 13,25;12,97;13,12;13,47;13,44;13,09;12,86;12,78;12,91;12,93;12,91;13,11
12,92;13,42;13,58;13,7;13,62;13,7;13,31;12,86;12,59;12,81;13,46;12,9
13,39;13,5;13,29;13,26;13,38;13,45;13,46;11,95;12;12,57;13,22;12,88
12,48;13,76;13,7;13,77;13,08;13,48;13,25;12,31;12,56;12,56;12,95;13,38
12,52;14,07;14,46;14,13;13,98;14,07;13,92;12,7;13,01;12,79;13;13,13

Comment: The default behaviour in csv.reader is to use commas as separators. You'll want to specify that your data is semi colon delimited

Comment: I think it's using semi colons by default because of the comas , could this be becuase I'm using comas instead of points because I'm in france?

Comment: what does your csv file look like?

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham  It's in the comments above

Comment: @Tetra ok I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not clear how you are trying to use the CSV module. First, by default, the csv module is going to use comma separated values, not semicolon separated values.

But either way, let's try writing some code:

```
import csv

class MyDialect(csv.excel):
    delimiter = ';'

with open('in.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, MyDialect())
    data = list(reader)

data = [[float(elem.replace(',', '.')) for elem in line] for line in data]

for line in data:
    print line
```

#### in.csv

```
13,25;12,97;13,12;13,47;13,44;13,09;12,86;12,78;12,91;12,93;12,91;13,11
12,92;13,42;13,58;13,7;13,62;13,7;13,31;12,86;12,59;12,81;13,46;12,9
13,39;13,5;13,29;13,26;13,38;13,45;13,46;11,95;12;12,57;13,22;12,88
12,48;13,76;13,7;13,77;13,08;13,48;13,25;12,31;12,56;12,56;12,95;13,38
12,52;14,07;14,46;14,13;13,98;14,07;13,92;12,7;13,01;12,79;13;13,13
```

#### stdout

```
[13.25, 12.97, 13.12, 13.47, 13.44, 13.09, 12.86, 12.78, 12.91, 12.93, 12.91, 13.11]
[12.92, 13.42, 13.58, 13.7, 13.62, 13.7, 13.31, 12.86, 12.59, 12.81, 13.46, 12.9]
[13.39, 13.5, 13.29, 13.26, 13.38, 13.45, 13.46, 11.95, 12.0, 12.57, 13.22, 12.88]
[12.48, 13.76, 13.7, 13.77, 13.08, 13.48, 13.25, 12.31, 12.56, 12.56, 12.95, 13.38]
[12.52, 14.07, 14.46, 14.13, 13.98, 14.07, 13.92, 12.7, 13.01, 12.79, 13.0, 13.13]
```

Comment: I'm using a french version of excel where commas are the equivilent of dots.

Comment: @Tetra: I'm aware of that.

Comment: So my default CSV module uses commas.

Comment: @Tetra: Please correct me if I'm wrong. Your csv file is organized as `number;number;number` and a number is defined as `123,456` where the comma separates the integer part and the fractional part of the value.

Comment: @Tetra: Then... is there any issue with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import csv
data=[]
import re
with open("out.csv","r") as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
              print row
              data+=[x.split(",") for x in row]
        print(data)

print("Calculate COV")

flattened = [float(x) for y in data for x in y]
```

Comment: I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marc/Desktop/Python/Metal Loss/GML3.py", line 43, in <module>
    flattened = [float(x) for y in spl for x in y if x]
  File "C:/Users/Marc/Desktop/Python/Metal Loss/GML3.py", line 43, in <listcomp>
    flattened = [float(x) for y in spl for x in y if x]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '13,25'

Comment: I missed the ; I will fix it now